# how to label and store each time slot everyday in arraylist

Tags: java, timeslots

I created time slot fro every 30 minutes. but I don't know how to label each time slot from Monday to Friday in an array. this is example of how I want to label my timeslot.

```
MS1 -> Monday 0800-0830
MS2 -> Monday 0830-0900

.
.
TS1 -> Tuesday 0800-0830
TS2 -> Tuesday 0830-0900
...
FS16 -> Friday 0530->0600
```

---

```
//create date(day and time)
public static Date newDate(Day day, int hour, int minute){
    return new Date(day, new TimeSlot(hour, minute));}

//create date with parameters
public static Date newDate(Day day, int minute){
    return new Date(day, new TimeSlot(minute));}
```

---

this is how i create my time slot in timeslot class.

```
//getter for hour
    public int getHour(){return hour;}
    //param hour the hour to set
    public void setHour(int hour){
        //24 hours
        if((hour >= 0) && (hour < 24)){
            this.hour = hour;}}


    //getter for minute
    public int getMinute(){return minute;}
    //param minute the minute to set
    public void setMinute(int minute){
        if(minute >0){
            this.hour += minute/60;
            this.minute = 30 * ((minute % 60) / 30);}
        else{
            minute = 0;}}
```

so if i store using 2d array. it's gonna be like this right? so the value index indicates every 30 minutes aite?

```
mondayTimeSlot.add(new TimeSlot(0));
mondayTimeSlot.add(new TimeSlot(1));
....
fridayTimeSlot.add(new TimeSlot(15));
```

Comment: Is `Date` of type `java.util.Date` or is it a custom class that you created? In the former case the code does not compile, since `java.util.Date` does not have the constructor you are using. If you are using custom class, you probably should include its details.
Moreover, what are you exactly willing to achieve? It is possible that `Map` may suit you better than array, but I need more specific details to tell for sure.

Comment: Date class is a custom class. the date class is to set the day and time(every 30 minutes). i'm trying to create time slots for scheduling system using genetic algorithm for my university. i don't know how to label each slot for each day and store the time slot.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect your data with a 2d array sorting by the days of the week. Something like this:

```
List<List<TimeSlot>> timeSlotsSortedByDay = new ArrayList<>();
List<TimeSlot> sundayTimeSlots = new ArrayList<>();
//Add all the time slots for sunday
sundayTimeSlots.add(new TimeSlot(30));
...
//Add sunday to main list
timeSlotsSortedByDay.add(sundayTimeSlots);
//Do the rest of the days using the same idea. 
...
//Access time slots for a given day
timeSlotsSortedByDay.get(0); //All time slots for sunday
timeSlotsSortedByDay.get(1); //All time slots for monday
```

You can even sort the individual days if you build out a custom `Comparator` for your `TimeSlot` class.

```
//Example if you want to iterate over all timeSlots for monday
for (int i=0; i<timeSlotsSortedByDay.get(1).size(); i++){ 
    timeSlotsSortedByDay.get(1).get(i).getHour(); //Do something with hour
    timeSlotsSortedByDay.get(1).get(i).getMinute(); //Do something with minute
}
```

Comment: it's okay. just confused about how it stores every 30 minutes slots.

Comment: @Noren it stores whatever `TimeSlots` you give it. If you want to create a `TimeSlot` every 30 min and add it you can just make a `for` loop to do that for you, looping over 30 min intervals.